# Q: 4 Channel Optocoupler to convert auto 12V signal to 5V Arduino

Tags: arduino, opto-isolator, automotive, isolator

I'm trying to connect an Arduino to my car. I'm planning on using the switched 12V (potentially 11V to 14.4V) car system as inputs into the Arduino. The Arduino will be running on 5V, provided by a sealed buck converter connected to the cars 12V system, so they will ultimately share a ground.

So starting out, I was looking at an LTV816 optocoupler, but since I need 4 channels, I looked at the Vishay ILQ55. Below is my first run at the circuit. On the left will be a 4 channel connector to the cars 12V system. On the right, the opto outputs would connect to an Arduino (likely a Seeeduino RP2040, as it's a small cheap package). I have not sized the resistors yet, so I know those are wrong. With 4 channels, is using a diode on each channel the best way to isolate each of the inputs from each other to the Arduino? Am I understanding this right?

I also read a question about using a DN2530 to further isolate the left side, but I'm assuming I would need one of those for each of the car connections?

This is just a project for myself, not commercial, so if I have to spend a bit more to build a more reliable system, I'm happy to do it. Feel free to critique and suggest other ways of doing this if you think of a better way. Thanks!

[image: 4 channel optocoupler circuit]

Reference:

https://www.snapeda.com/parts/ILQ55/Vishay+Semiconductor+Opto+Division/view-part/
https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/XIAO-RP2040-with-CircuitPython/
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00C63TLCC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1
https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/8r4rb7/interfacing_12v_logic_lines_to_a_33v_mcu/
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwX7D.gif

EDIT:

So based on "vir"s suggestion to further protect the inputs on the left, I added Littlefuse TPSMA6L13A on the 12V input side.
[image: Modified Circuit]

Comment: You certainly have the right idea isolating your inputs from the notoriously dirty 12V system but you also need to plan for transients that can top 100V.  Whether you put a TVS or something else on the input to your opto depends on the application but you definitely need something on there to keep it from frying.  There's some good introductory information here: https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/application_notes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_automotive_circuit_protection_using_automotive_tvs_diodes_application_note.pdf.pdf

Comment: I'd say optocouplers are overkill, there is no need for galvanic isolation. A voltage divider with somewhat high resistor values, a small capacitor and a zener diode for clamping works just fine. Never seen it fail, with tens of thousands devices out in different vehicles/machines. Power supply is what one really needs to protect, most of-the-shelf buck converters won't do.

Comment: I second Klas’ comments. I would also suggest that you visit the local auto wrecker/recycler and get yourself an electronic module from a car and see how they solve the problem. In my area we have some self serve wreckers with published prices. Something like a body management computer. If you choose a popular car you should be able to get the wiring diagram so you can see what are inputs, outputs etc. the idea is to get hints rather than a complete solution from this. $10 or so gets you some learning. Find a dumped car - free! Also look at ‘ megasquirt’

Comment: It seems like it may be simpler to just purchase an off the shelf level shifter like this: https://www.ezsbc.com/product/ls2/

Comment: Regarding your addition of the TPSMA6L13A parts - that's not how you use a TVS diode. They should be placed in parallel with the inputs (between each input and Ground), not in series.